# Eigenvalue problem and determinant of an index-factorized matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Consider a complex square matrix $A$ whose entries are defined by:
$$ A_{kq} = f(k) f^*(q) \, , $$
where $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a discrete function of an index and $^*$ stands for the complex conjugation. I have to deal with the eigenvalue problem associated with this matrix.

Obviously, this is a Hermitian matrix, so it is diagonalizable and it has real eigenvalues. It is also easy to see that it is (at least) positive semi-definite since, given the unitary matrix $U$ which diagonalizes it:
$$ \lambda_j = (U^{-1} A U)_{jj} = \sum_{k,q} U^*_{kj} f(k) f^*(q) U_{qj} = \left( \sum_k U^*_{kj} f(k) \right) \left( \sum_q U_{qj} f^*(q) \right) = \left| \sum_k U^*_{kj} f(k) \right|^2 \geq 0 $$
where $\lambda_j$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.
My question is: is there something else that can be said with a generic $f$? In particular, I would be interested in the determinant of $A$ and possibly understand under what conditions $A$ is singular.

**EDIT**: Thanks to a kind soul, in the comments we figured out that if $A$ is a $m \times m$ matrix it has at least $m-1$ eigenvalues equal to zero (therefore it is always singular), and the only non-zero eigenvalue is equal to the trace of $A$. This comes from the fact that every $2 \times 2$ principal minor is equal to zero, so that:
$$ \sum_{i < j} \lambda_i \lambda_j = 0 $$
which together with the condition $\lambda_i \geq 0$ leads to the assertion. Since the post is not closed yet, I'll add another question with an additional layer of complexity (if that's allowed, otherwise please let me know). What if $A$ is now given by:
$$ A_{kq} = \sum_n c_n f_n(k) f_n^*(q) $$
where $c_n \geq 0$ are non-negative real constants and $f_n$ are different discrete functions labelled by an index $n$? It is still Hermitian and positive semi-definite, but what about its determinant and its spectrum? It can be seen that the $2\times 2$ principal minors take the form:
$$ \sum_{n<m} c_n c_m \left| f_n(\bar{k}) f_m(\bar{q}) - f_m(\bar{k}) f_n(\bar{q}) \right|^2 $$
for some pair $(\bar{k},\bar{q})$. In general, it seems to be a non-zero quantity, so the previous argument does not apply. Any idea?

Comment: have you tried to work out the determinant in the $2\times 2$ case?

Comment: I just tried in the $2 \times 2$ case and in the $3 \times 3$ case, and the determinant should be zero. I'm starting to think that $A$ is always singular (unless it's a $1 \times 1$). There's probably a simple pattern there, but I cannot figure it out already. I'll add this information to the question, thanks.

Comment: try writing $A = \mathbf b \mathbf b^*$ for $\mathbf b=\begin{bmatrix}
f(1) \\ 
f(2) \\  
\vdots \\ 
f(m)\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Alternatively, since you've proven that every $2\times 2$ prinicipal submatrix has zero determinant -- this gives you information about the characteristic polynomial, i.e. that $\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j\lt i}\lambda_i \lambda_j = 0$ (i.e. summing over all $\binom{m}{2}$ products) but you've proven all $\lambda_k\geq 0$ -- this implies that there must be at least $m-1$ eigenvalues = 0.  Assuming nontrivial $f$ then $\text{trace}\big(A\big) \gt 0$ so it has exactly one eigenvalue $\gt 0$.

Comment: Oh, this last one looks like a complete answer to my question, thank you very much! So, to sum up, if $c \equiv \sum_k |f(k)|^2 \neq 0$ then $c$ is an eigenvalue along with $m-1$ zeros, while if $c = 0$ we are simply looking at $A = 0$. Seems neat!